# How to divide the number into parts with Groovy?

Tags: groovy

There is a number with format DDDDDRRRPC. It is necessary to separate it on parts C, P, RRR, DDDDDD. I'm not sure, but it may looks on Java like this

```
String U_id_str = String.valueOf(U_id);  
int k_num = Integer.parseInt(U_id_str.substring(9))
int gend = Integer.parseInt(U_id_str.substring(8, 9)) 
int P_num = Integer.parseInt(U_id_str.substring(5, 8))
int birth_num = Integer.parseInt(U_id_str.substring(0, 5))
```

How can this be done on Groovy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use regex matching with Groovy's [multiple assignment operator](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.3.8/html/documentation/#_multiple_assignment) to simplify the code. Consider following example:

```groovy
import java.util.regex.Pattern

try {
    String U_id_str = "2100304213"

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(/^([0-9]{5})([0-9]{3})([0-9])([0-9])$/)

    def (_, birthNum, pNum, gend, kNum) = (U_id_str =~ pattern)[0]

    println "birthNum = ${birthNum}, pNum = ${pNum}, gend = ${gend}, kNum = ${kNum}"

} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
    println "Input string does not match regular expression..."
}
```

In this example we use pattern `^([0-9]{5})([0-9]{3})([0-9])([0-9])$` which defines 4 parts of the initial number (represented as a string). In the 4th line we test if input string matches given pattern using `=~` operator which returns `java.util.regex.Matcher` object and we assign each matching part to variables `birthNum`, `pNum`, `gend` and `kNum`. For safety reasons we execute this code inside try-catch block, because `(U_id_str =~ pattern)[0]` may throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if input string does not match given pattern.

And last but not least - keep in mind, that matcher returns matching parts as strings, so if you want to pass these variables to methods that expect e.g. `Integer`, you have to explicitly cast them with `Integer.valueOf(...)`.

Output:

```
birthNum = 21003, pNum = 042, gend = 1, kNum = 3
```

Comment: Hey, good work, thanks a lot. Can you help me some more? I want to make a check for 'gend'. If  (gend % 2 == 0), then gend_w = "man", else gend_w = "woman"